# ternary analogues of the Pell equations

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

We know well about the Pell equations: $x^2 -ny^2=1$ and some variants of them. Criterions about the existence of nontrivial solutions of homogeneous equations $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$ are also well-known.

Then, how about the 3-v analogues of the Pell equations? I mean, the diophantine equations of this type: $x^2+ay^2+bz^2=1$, where $a, b $ integers. Is there an extensive survey article on them?

Comment: maybe it is trivial... in that case, what would it be on $x^2+ay^2+bz^2=n^2$? I guess these are quite nontrivial, according to some brute-force computations.

Comment: For some particular cases it is possible to write such.   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575931/what-integers-can-be-represented-by-the-quadratic-form-4x2-3y2-z2/777067#777067  Can always be reduced to a Pell equation. And his decisions will determine the solutions of this equation.  Formulas are bulky and while it's not necessary.

Comment: For $$x^2+ay^2-z^2=k$$ , $$x=(t^2-as^2+k)/(2t),\\y=s,\\z=(t^2+as^2-k)/(2t)$$

Comment: @AlexSam Thanks. Could you generalize your formula, when $c \ne -1$?

Comment: @user362921 No.

Comment: If the equation is.  $ax^2+by^2=cz^2+k$ solutions can be.  And there may be infinitely many.  This means you can write a formula for the parametrization of solutions.  For such a case, if the coefficients are all positive  $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=k$ if solutions exist, their number of course.  What kind of formula to say if it in principle can not be? One task is much more difficult the second. Require that in principle cannot exist.

Comment: @individ yeah, it's a kind of conic and I expect there is a parametrization of solutions. And there are some trivial cases; for $x^2+ay^2+bz^2=1$, I should suppose at least $a $ or $b $ is negative. Then?

Comment: Then decisions can be. The truth is not always.

Comment: @individ I guess more replies are useless... you don't give any proofs nor references. I don't want your "bulky" formulas, but a mathematical demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that [Cassels](http://store.doverpublications.com/0486466701.html) does this material, pages 301-309. There is quite a big difference based on whether $x^2 - A y^2 - B z^2$ is isotropic or not, meaning there is an integer solution to  $x^2 - A y^2 - B z^2=0$ with $x,y,z$ not all equal to zero. When the form is isotropic, pages 301-303, especially the proof of Lemma 5.4 and discussion on page 303.

Anisotropic is harder and the sign of the target number matters; compare Theorem 6.2 on page 305 to Theorem 6.3 on page 306.

Alright, went through the easiest example, I can see where his notation is a little different from what I expected, but he is consistent, that is what matters. In solving $x_1 x_3 - x_2^2 = 1,$ we have a single orbit, that being his $c = (1,0,1)$ from the paragraph between 5.19 and 5.20 on page 303. The result for 
$$ x^2 - y^2 - z^2 = 1  $$ is, with
$$ \alpha \delta - \beta \gamma = 1 $$ and
$$ \alpha + \beta + \gamma + \delta \equiv 0 \pmod 2, $$
$$ \left( \frac{\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2 + \delta^2}{2}, \; \;   \frac{\alpha^2 - \beta^2 + \gamma^2 - \delta^2}{2}, \; \; \alpha \beta + \gamma \delta  \right) $$

```
? p =   ( a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 )^2 - ( a^2 - b^2 + c^2 - d^2 )^2 - (2 * a * b + 2 * c * d   )^2
%7 = 4*d^2*a^2 - 8*d*c*b*a + 4*c^2*b^2
? q = 4 *  ( a * d - b * c)^2
%8 = 4*d^2*a^2 - 8*d*c*b*a + 4*c^2*b^2
? p - q
%9 = 0
```